# Derriving the taylor series for $e^{\frac{\ln{(x+1)}}{x}}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

So I'm trying to find the Taylor polynomial of $e^{\frac{\ln{(x+1)}}{x}}$ around $x=0$ up to order $1$, however I encounter quite the problem.

We know that:
$$\ln{(1+x)}=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)$$
Hence, $$\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{x}=1-\frac{x}{2}+O(x^2)$$
Now, the Taylor expansion for $\exp$ is:
$$e^ u=1+ u + \frac{u^2}{2}+...$$
Thus,
$$e^{\frac{\ln{(x+1)}}{x}} =1+ {\frac{\ln{(x+1)}}{x}} + \frac{1}{2} \left({\frac{\ln{(x+1)}}{x}}\right)^2+...$$
Now,
$$\left({\frac{\ln{(x+1)}}{x}}\right)^2=\left(1-\frac{x}{2}+O(x^2)\right)\left(1-\frac{x}{2}+O(x^2)\right)=1-x+O(x^2)$$
Continuing this way, we observe that all $\left({\frac{\ln{(x+1)}}{x}}\right)^n$ will contain a $x^1$ term, how can we then actually find the coefficient of the taylor expansion of $x^1$, and the constant term, since we will always have a $1$ in the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct to expand $f(x)=\exp\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)}x\right)$ this way because $g(x)=\frac{\ln(1+x)}x$ doesn't have limit 0 at $x=0$.

Here is the correct way to get the desired Taylor expansion :

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x) & = & \exp\left(1-\frac x2+O(x^2)\right)\\
& = & e \cdot \exp\left(-\frac x2+O(x^2\right)\\
& = & e\cdot\left(1-\frac x2+O(x^2)\right)\\
& = & e-\frac{ex}2+O(x^2)
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Actually,$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(x+1)}x=\log'(1)=1.$$

Comment: Superb typo !!!

Comment: @Adren why is it that $\exp(-\frac{x}{2}+O(x^2))= (1-\frac{x}{2}+O(x^2)$?

Comment: That’s because $e^u=1+u+O(u^2)$ as $u\to0$

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the derivative of $e^{\frac{\ln{(x+1)}}{x}}$ and evaluate them at $0$ to get the expansion:

$$\frac{d}{dx}e^{\frac{\ln{(x+1)}}{x}}=(\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\ln{(x+1)}}{x})e^{\frac{\ln{(x+1)}}{x}}$$

You can see that the derivative at $0$ of $e^{\frac{\ln{(x+1)}}{x}}$ is equal to the derivatives of $\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}$ at $0$ multiplied by $e$ since $\lim_{x\to 0}e^{\frac{\ln{(x+1)}}{x}}=e$

Hence the taylor expansion of $e^{\frac{\ln{(x+1)}}{x}}$ up to order one is $e-\frac{ex}{2}+O(x^2)$.

Comment: Your argument is OK for the first derivative.  (So it works to solve this problem.)  But it is not OK for higher derivatives.  So your assertion in the last sentence is wrong for Taylor expansions of order ${}\ge 2$.

Comment: @Gedgar you are right, i missed it.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to compose the series from inside to outside
$$y=e^{\frac{\ln{(x+1)}}{x}} \implies \log(y)=\frac{\ln{(x+1)}}{x}$$ Starting as you did
$$\log(y)=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}+O\left(x^3\right)$$Now, continuing with Taylor
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=e-\frac{e x}{2}+\frac{11 e x^2}{24}+O\left(x^3\right)$$

Comment: in the last step when raising everything to $e$, do you use the taylor series? What's going on there? How do you simplify e raised to the series?

Comment: @William. Yes, for sure. I wrote it